# Trouble with domain delegation

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, domain, bind, delegation

I suspect I have a problem with domain delegation.

Notes:

- Following addresses and names are examples
- I have two public static IPs and own a domain name
- I'm using Debian 9 and Bind 9

I want something like this (IPs are public):
on `0.0.0.0` is DNS server `ns1.example.com` which points `example.com` to `0.0.0.1`.

I succesfully configured `ns1.example.com` as authoritative and forwarding DNS server (with above configuration).
I DMZ port 53 (UDP).

Next step I tried to delegate domain (`example.com`) from Registrar's DNS server to my own (`ns1.example.com`) I get "wrong record".
When I contacted Registar's helpdesk the tell me I did not register the server, and I should contact my hosting provider (which is me...). What do they mean?

Comment: For IP addresses, please use the designated ones for documentation: 192.0.2.0/24 or 198.51.100.0/24 or 203.0.113.0/24. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737

Comment: Note that DNS does not use only UDP, but also TCP so if you filter that you will get problems. Also it is a bad idea to have the same server being authoritative and recursive (is this what you mean by 'forwarding'?).

Comment: It would help if you get the true names involved, that will be far quicker to solve the problem. If you are using a gTLD based domain name you need to register the name server at registry, through your registrar. They should be able to help you otherwise you can change it. It also depends if the nameserver is internal/external and in-bailiwick or not. In short, you do not provide enough information to help you.

Comment: You need to ask your registrar to set up what are known as "glue records".  Once that is done, you can use ns1/ns2.example.com as the primary and secondary name servers on your actual domain registration for example.com

Answer (score 0):

Because ns1 is under example.com you must "register" this IP with them, these are called GLUE records.  Essentially A records added to the zone `.com.` so servers know what IPs to query.